# $\#imagef=\#imagef^*$, order of image of dual and image of original homomorphism is the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, duality-theorems, characters

Let $M$ be an abelian group
Let $M^*=Hom_{\Bbb{Z}}(M,\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$ be pontryagin dual of $M$.

Let $M$ be a finite group.
Let $M'$ be an abelian group. Let $f:M\to M'$ be a homomorphism of abelian group.
Let  $f^*: M'^*\to M^*$ be a map defined by $g\to f・g$. Then,
I want to prove $\#imagef=\#imagef^*$.

I know $\#M=\#M^*$. I'm having difficulty solving this problem because I have no idea of how to relate $imagef$ and $Imagef^*$.
What is a tactics to tackle this kind of problem?

I want to solve this problem on my own, but I can't take the first step. I would be very happy if you could give me a hint, guidance, or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $K=\ker f$ and consider the Pontryagin dual of the exact sequence $0\to K\to M\to M'$.

More details are hidden below.

> Since Pontryagin duality is an exact functor, the dual sequence $$(M')^*\to M^*\to K^*\to 0$$ is also exact.  Now just observe that these exact sequences give $|\operatorname{im} f|=|M|/|K|$ and $|\operatorname{im} f^*|=|M^*|/|K^*|$.  In fact, more strongly, if $I=\operatorname{im} f$ then there is a short exact sequence $0\to K\to M\to I\to 0$ and dualizing this shows that $I^*$ is the kernel of $M^*\to K^*$, i.e. the image of $f^*$, so there is actually a canonical isomorphism $(\operatorname{im} f)^*\cong \operatorname{im} f^*$.

Comment: Let $0\to \Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}$, the latter is $\times 2$ map. Pontryagin dual of second map is also $\times 2 :\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}$ is not surjection. But as you commented, since $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ is injective, it should be an exact functor. Where am I missing ?

Comment: The dual of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$, and multiplication by $2$ is surjective $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think Pontryagin dual of $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ is $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$(Profinite completion of $\Bbb{Z}$. If dual of $\Bbb{Z}$ is $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$, then dual of dual of $\Bbb{Z}$ is dual of $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ and that is $\hat{Z}$. Then $\Bbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$. But $\Bbb{Z}$ is not ismorphic to $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$. Where am I missing ?

Comment: The dual of the dual is not always the original group; that only works for finite groups.

Comment: (To get a similar duality that works for arbitrary abelian groups, you need to use $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and put a topology on the dual group.  Then the dual of any abelian group naturally becomes a compact topological group and its continuous dual is the original group.)

Comment: May I ask one more thing I'm confused ?  Neukirch's 'algebraic number theory' defines Pontryagin dual of torsion abelian group $M$ as $Hom_{\Bbb{Z}}(M,\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$ but another book sometimes defines it as $Hom_{\text{continuous}}(M,\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$ for topological group $M$.  According to your explanation, these definition is not the same for infinite abelian group, but is it ok to define Pontryagin dual of infinite abelian group in such a dirrefent manner ? Which is a standard one ?

Comment: My experience is that "Pontryagin dual" usually refers to continuous homomorphisms from a locally compact topological abelian group to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, but sometimes it is also used to refer to homomorphisms from a finite abelian group to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.  The latter is essentially a special case of the former.

Comment: Then in this question, we shouldn't define Pontryagin dual like in my question because $M'$ is not necessarily a finite abelian group  ?

Comment: I wouldn't use that term for it myself.  But it's just a word, and you can use it however you want as long as you are clear about what you mean.

Comment: In the context of Pontryagin dual, what topology is on $M$ ? Does that depend on situation ? What in my mind is $M=E(K)$ where $E/K$ is an elliptic curve over a number field.

Comment: Do you know what about dual of $\text{ker}$ ? In my opinion , $\text{ker}f^*\cong (\text{coker}f)^*$ by dualizing $M\to M'\to cokerf\to 0$.

Comment: My issue of concern is as follows. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882102/does-textimf-cong-textkerf-hold-pontryag