# $\text{Im}(f)=\text{ker}(\widehat{f})$, written in 'Galois cohomology of elliptic curves' by Coates and Sujata

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, duality-theorems, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a number field and $K_v$ be the completion of $K$ at the place $v$. Consider an elliptic curve $E/K$ over $K$.

Let $f: H^1(G_K,E[2])\to \bigoplus_v H^1(G_{K_v},E[2])$ be a natural map.

For $M$: profinite abelian group $M$, we let $\widehat{M}=\text{Hom}(M, \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$ be the Pontryagin dual of $M$.
For group hom $f$ between profinite groups, we denote $\widehat{f}$ by its dual hom.

In $1.2$ of Coates Sujata's 'Galois cohomology of elliptic curves', they states

> $\text{Im}(f)=\text{ker}(\widehat{f})$

(They put $M=E[2]$ and $W_v(M)$ in the book as the image of Kummer map).
Why does this hold ?
In general situation, such a = does not hold (cf. [Does $\text{Im}(f)\cong \text{Ker}(f^*)$ hold? Pontryagin dual](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882102/does-textimf-cong-textkerf-hold-pontryagin-dual)).

However, in their paper, they write about this completeness as if it were a matter of course. How do they prove it?

Comment: You seem confused. For a start, the Pontryagin dual of a profinite module is not profinite in general. Coates and Sujatha are actually only considering *finite* modules, and the dual of a finite module is finite. But you cannot apply their result to $H^1(G_K, E)$, which is a shorthand for $H^1(G_K, E(\overline{K}))$, since $E(\overline{K})$ is not discrete (and not profinite either).

Comment: The statement you are looking for about Pontryagin duality is not that $Im(f)$ is the **dual** of $ker(\hat{f})$, but rather $Im(f)$ is the **annihilator** of $ker(\hat{f})$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @David Loeffler. We apply their result to the case of finite $E[2]$. I don't understand your second comment because what I aim to prove is that $\text{ker}(\widehat{f}) = \text{Im}(f)$ in $\bigoplus_v H^1(G_{K_v},E[2])$.

Comment: Sorry,also, there was a mistake regarding the part about $G_K$; in their book, the proof was for $G_S$, not $G_K$, regarding the finite set of places,$S$. What I wanted to ask about was the exactness of the parts concerning $β_{M_D}$ and $\widehat{β_M}$ in the sequence of the celebrated Poitou-Tate's in section $1.3$ in the book. However, my explanation was poorly done, sorry.